# How to add multiple user input data to a sigle dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class, dictionary

In the following code, I can store only up to two user inputs in the dictionary and concatenate them to a single dataframe. And if the same function is called again with different input, it overwrites the data entered before. How can I add multiple user input data to a single dataframe whenever the loop is running?
class CreateMarklist:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.student_name=None
    self.student_marks=None
    self.df_1 = None
    self.df_2 = None
    self.df_3 = None
    self.dict_1=None

def student_record(self):
    n=int(input("Enter number of students"))
    for i in rage(n): 
        self.student_name=input("Enter student name")
        self.student_marks=int(input("Enter marks")
        self.df_1=pd.Dataframe([dict_1])
        self.dict_1= {
            "Student Name" :self.student_name,
            "Marks" : self.student_marks}      
        self.df_2=pd.Dataframe([self.dict_1]),index=[1])
        self.df_3=pd.concat([self.df_1,self.df_2])
    print(self.df_3)

obj=CreateMarklist()
obj.student_record()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing dataframe operations for all of the adds? Would it be simpler perhaps to build a dictionary of students and then create a single dataframe at the final step?

Comment: @G.Anderson Yes, I am in need of a program that will concatenate all of the adds because everytime a new student's mark is to be added,I need to have that in the same dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer guys,

```py
import pandas as pd
class CreateMarklist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.student_name = None
        self.student_marks = None
        self.df_1 = None
        self.df_2 = None
        self.df_3 = None
        self.dict_1 = None    

    def student_record(self):
        n = int(input("Enter number of students"))
        for i in range(n):
            self.student_name = input("Enter student name")
            self.student_marks = int(input("Enter marks")) 
            self.dict_1= {
                "Student Name" :self.student_name,
                "Marks" : self.student_marks
            }
            self.df_1 = pd.DataFrame([self.dict_1])
            self.df_2 = pd.read_excel("excel_name.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
            self.df_2 = pd.concat([self.df_2, self.df_1], ignore_index=True)
            self.df_2.to_excel("excel_name.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
            self.df_3 = pd.read_excel("excel_name.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
        print(self.df_3)

obj = CreateMarklist()
obj.student_record()
```

This will append data whenever the loop is called, and when you run the script again, your data will get appended to excel having data from previous runs.